# Overloading of inherited class with specific template value

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading, member

So, I know with a class that uses a template, you can return a class of the same type with a specific template type in a member function, such as:

```
template <typename T>
struct f {

    T val;

    f(T val) : val(val) {};

    virtual f<float> GetVal() { return f<float>(val); };

};
```

So that way, I can have

```
f<int>::GetVal()
```

return a type of `f<float>`

This works perfectly fine, until I try to do the same thing with an inherited class, such as:

```
template <typename T>
struct f2 : public f<T> {

    f2(T val) : f(val) {};

    virtual f2<float> GetVal() { return f2<float>(val); };

};
```

If I replace the float in the return part with T, then it works perfectly fine, as expected. But when I use the `f2<float>` return type, it gives the error

```
error C2555: 'f2<T>::GetVal': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'f<T>::GetVal'
```

But I would expect `f2<float>` to be covariant with `f<float>`.

What is the problem here, and is there a way I can make this overloaded member function return what I want it to?

Comment: No, they both need to be a reference or pointer to be covariant.

Comment: Is there a way I can get it to return a non-pointer to that type, or is that the only way I can fix the error?

Comment: I'd say it's the only *clean* way to fix the error without redesigning things.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying the achieve, but maybe [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) can help you:

```
template <typename T, typename Derived>
struct f {
    T val;
    f(T val) : val(val) {};
    Derived<float> GetVal() { return Derived<float>(val); };

};

template <typename T>
struct f2 : public f<T, f2<T>> {
    f2(T val) : f(val) {};
};
```